# Yii ORDER column data in view

Tags: php, yii

In my DB there is a column call **`status`** with four type of data **NEW**, **RESUBMITTED**, **APPROVE** and **REJECT**.

I have successfully "ORDER BY DESC" of the **`status`** to VIEW. However, what I really want is the  **`status`** can list by :

1. REJECT
2. APPROVE
3. RESUBMITTED
4. NEW

Currently for the "ORDER BY DESC" is:

1. RESUBMITTED
2. REJECT
3. NEW
4. APPROVE

**In Model I added this code for ORDER:**

```
public function scopes() {
    return array(
        'bystatus' => array('order' => 'status DESC'),
    );
}
```

**In Controller action:**

```
public function actionAppListPage()
{
    $count = '0';
    $id = Yii::app()->user->getState('id');
    $models = Developers::model()->bystatus()->findAll('developer_id='.$id);
    $this->render('applist',array('models'=>$models,'count'=>$count));
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

How to order the status I want ? Or any other suggestion to do that? Thanks

Comment: what is the data type of "status" column??

Comment: ok. then, the result you get is totaly correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your order like  :

```
public function scopes() {
    return array(
        'bystatus'  => array(
            'order' => "(CASE status WHEN 'REJ' THEN 0 WHEN 'APPROVE' THEN 1 WHEN 'RESUBMITTED' THEN 2 WHEN 'NEW' THEN 3 ELSE 4 END)",
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: sorry it doesn't order that I wish... result is 1. APPROVE 2. RESUBMITTED 3. NEW 4. REJECT

Comment: no I mean the code that u give me just now the result is order by 1. APPROVE 2. RESUBMITTED 3. NEW 4. REJECT

Comment: Oh now can make it ! I forgot in db not call REJECT is REJ ... Thanks u so much !

Comment: u can undo back the previous answer ~ sorry xP and Thanks again =)

Comment: @TheSmile I've just approved your editing suggestion!